# TFS command line not working through Jenkins

Tags: tfs, jenkins

I am new to this, so please excuse my ignorance if this is something very basic.

I use the following commands in the 'Execute windows Batch command' tab in a Jenkins job -

```
cd "C:\Data\Projects\<project name>\00_Mainline" 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get "$/Analytical/<project name>/00_Mainline" /force /recursive
```

This works well if I type it in a command prompt; but when this is run from Jenkins, I get the following error -

> Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.

After going through several threads in this site, I added

```
pushd "C:\Data\Projects\<project name>\00_Mainline"
```

to the top of the script. But this didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Sudhi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't specified otherwise I'm going to assume Jenkins is running under a different user account, in which case there may not be a workspace for the Jenkins account.

In any case, in Jenkins you might need to use the `tf workspace` command to create a new workspace, and then the `tf workfold` command to set up a folder mapping before you can do the `tf get`.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard! I changed the user from the default system user to my login credentials and it worked!